# nested fragments for android api level 8

Tags: android, android-fragments, nested

i am wondering if it's possible to use nested fragments ( programatically ) for an application that has minSDK 8 , i was looking since days but i can't find a clear answer.
this is the scenario i am trying to implement :

**Activity-A** instanciate a new **DialogFragment** to show , in **onCreateView()** for my DialogFragment i'm adding another fragment dynamically (it's a map) and trying to get it back in same onCreateView() method. getting always nullPointerException.

is it possible or should i change the whole architecture ?